# Why using a String parse date can't find result in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, date, hibernate-criteria

I'm using mysql database, column type is date.

Why when I using a parameter which is String parse to Date that can't find result.

And when I using "new Date()" that can find result.

Dao :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<vo> query = builder.createQuery(vo.class);
Root<vo> root = query.from(vo.class);

query.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("id"), id), builder.equal(root.get("querydate"), queryDate));

vo result = session.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
```

main :

```
String qdate = "20190514";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date queryDate = sdf.parse(qdate);

// this can't find result!
vo data =  dao.queryByIdAndDate("SwnZMgFsE52J", queryDate);

// this can find result!
vo data =  dao.queryByIdAndDate("SwnZMgFsE52J", new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i suggest to capitalize the first letter of Java class. It's recommend to do it. Therefore your problem is linked to a mismatch between your date format and the format accepted from db. Try with a date formatted in this way: yyyy-MM-dd.
So in your main try this:

```
String qdate = "2019-05-14";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date queryDate = sdf.parse(qdate);
vo data =  dao.queryByIdAndDate("SwnZMgFsE52J", queryDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, the class name just for example, that's not my real class name.
I have tried different format like you said, but it's not working.
The final variable type is "Date", so I think has nothing to do with the format.
The only different is "Time"： "Wed May 15 00:00:00 CST 2019" & "Wed May 15 17:59:57 CST 2019".
Wed May 15 00:00:00 CST 2019 -> not found
Wed May 15 17:59:57 CST 2019 -> found.
That's what I don't understand.